# java strings with numbers

Tags: java

I am having a group of strings in Arraylist.

I want to remove all the strings with only numbers
and also strings like this : (0.75%),$1.5 ..basically everything that does not contain the characters.
2) I want to remove all special characters in the string before i write to the console.
"God should be printed God.
&quot;Including should be printed: quoteIncluding
'find should be find

Comment: I smell [regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: "..everything that does not contain characters.." That is the clue! Instead of thinking of 'removing' why not thinking of 'including', `A-Z` and `a-z` is only 26 + 26 alphabets you know..

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

Java boasts a very nice [Pattern class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that makes use of regular expressions.  You should definitely read up on that.  A good reference guide is [here.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

I was going to post a coding solution for you, but styfle beat me to it!  The only thing I was going to do different here was within the for loop, I would have used the Pattern and Matcher class, as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z][A-Z]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myArray.get(i));
    boolean match = m.matches();  
    //more code to get the string you want
}
```

But that too bulky.  styfle's solution is succinct and easy.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "characters," I'm assuming you mean only "a through z" and "A through Z." You probably want to use Regular Expressions (Regex) as D1e mentioned in a comment. Here is an example using the replaceAll method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(5);
        list.add("\"God");
        list.add("&quot;Including");
        list.add("'find");
        list.add("24No3Numbers97");
        list.add("w0or5*d;");

        for (String s : list) {
            s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]",""); //use whatever regex you wish
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is as follows:

> God
>   quotIncluding
>   find
>   NoNumbers
>   word

The replaceAll method uses a regex pattern and replaces all the matches with the second parameter (in this case, the empty string).